# css background image positioning is working differently in firefox

Tags: html, css

I am using an image as bottom line of a table cell.

```
 background-position: -14px bottom !important;
```

The above code is working fine for the background positioning of the image in all browser except Mozila.

So I changed to below code:

```
background-position: -14px 0!important;
```

It is also working fine in all browser but in Firefox it gives `1px` gap at the `bottom`.

What is the difference between the code as `bottom` and `0px`????

Please advice me,How to overide this issue to hide the `bottom 1px` gap?

Comment: Have a tried using a css reset to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
table { 
border-spacing:0;  /*  'cellspacing' equivalent  */
border-collapse:collapse;
}

table td, table th
{
padding: 0; /* 'cellpadding' equivalent */
}

table, th, td
{
border:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware there isn't a major difference between 0px and bottom, they're both telling the image to sit at the bottom of the div, however I do believe the problem stems from Firefox's user agent stylesheet.

Try putting a reset css before the rest of your CSS, this tends to clear up most issues with cross browser user agent stylesheet problems.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/